# Can't get the right SQL syntax using pymsql, error 1064

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error, pymysql

My output works in csv, but not when trying to insert it into mysql. I get the following error and have not been able to figure it out. I'm a novice so I may be missing something obvious. Same error in Python 2x and 3x.

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, title, content, start_date, end_date, initial_update) VALUES('reddit', 'h' at line 1")

mainDB_cnx = pymysql.connect(user='XXXX', password='XXXX',
                             host='XXXX',
                             database='Test', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8mb4")


with mainDB_cnx:
    mainDB_cursor = mainDB_cnx.cursor()
    mainDB_cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO reddit(site, site_url, key, title, content, start_date, end_date, initial_update) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%%Y-%%m-%%d'), STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%%Y-%%m-%%d'), STR_TO_DATE(%s,'%%Y-%%m-%%d'))",
        (["reddit", "http://www.reddit.com", url, title, content, datetime.strptime(date,'%d %B %Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime('2018-07-25','%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), datetime.strptime('2018-07-25','%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]))
    print("Successful")
```

Comment: A space between `reddit` and `(site, ...)`?

Comment: I tried that already, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Add a space between the aforementioned as well as after `VALUES`.

Comment: didn't work either, thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

`KEY` is a reserved word in the MySQL dialect of structured query language. See this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K

So you must wrap that column name in delimiters whenever you mention it.

Try

```
INSERT INTO reddit (side, site_url, `key`, title, ....
```

Or, better, don't use reserved words for the names of columns in your tables. The next programmer to work on your system will thank you.